# Lavachart insert values from database

Tags: database, laravel

```
  $datatable->addNumberColumn(' Grades ');
        $datatable->addNumberColumn(' grade | Grade ');
        $datatable->addNumberColumn(' Temprature  |  Temprature');

$grad = DB::table('grades')->lists('grade');

$datatable->addRow([$grade,10, 72]);
```

What i want to do is for example to add the row values in to the scatter plot the only way i can do is manual. i tried with a foreach loop but seems not be working. Is there a way to add the values in to the addRow from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the lists() method returns an array of all the grades, per your example.
So that means you would need to loop over the grades array, to get each grade, and addRow() with the individual grade.

I'm not really sure what you are trying to represent with two grade columns.

[Scatter Example](http://lavacharts.com/#example-scatter)

Comment: The problem is for example if i loop through the grades data i get a value example like 5987456145687. I can not say for example $datatable->addRow([$grades); because it sees it as 5987456145687.

Comment: I'm assuming your query returns a list of grades, correct? Such as  
    [59,87,45,61,45,68]

So, you should be able to loop over those values and add them to the datatable:  
    foreach ($grades as $grade) {
        $datatable->addRow([$grade, 10, 72]);
    }

Comment: if i just print the $grade inside the foreach loop i get values 598745614568 and if i add that $datatable->addRow([$grade, 10] thats seems not to be working for some reason. This is how it looks like http://puu.sh/pFO5T/acbd8c28ac.png

Comment: I should have asked earlier, but overlooked it. Why three columns? Scatter charts need two axes.

Comment: Im using 2 columns for now

Comment: Ok, per your example, are you trying to relate all $grades to the one temperature, of 10? If so, each $grade needs it's own row, with the temperature of 10. And if they all have the same temperature, then it will make a horizontal line of dots since the X axis varies and the Y stays constant

Comment: No i want to get all the values diffrently for example in the examples of lavacharts you add all the values manualy like this            ->addRow(['2004', 1000, 400])
         ->addRow(['2005', 1170, 460])
         ->addRow(['2006', 660, 1120])
         ->addRow(['2007', 1030, 54]); i want for example to put values which i get from the database in the chart if i loop through the data its not working but when i do that i only get one output for example 9,8,7,4,5,6. I hope you understand me better what i want

Comment: Do you have a Github account? (if not, pastebin or something similar) Can you start an issue there, with the code you are trying to create the datatable with, as well as a var_dump() of what the list() method returns? I'm having trouble interpreting what you want without seeing it, and I want to help you sort this out